# Matching Parentheses with Regex in Flex

Tags: regex, apache-flex

For some reason I can't seem to match a parentheses in Flex using Regex to save my life.

What's wrong with this?

```
var commandTxt:String = "switchview(adf)";
var switchViewArray:Array = commandTxt.match(new RegExp("switchview\(", "i"));
```

I've tried dozens of things, but I can't seem to get a match the parentheses.  What's the catch here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I never used Flex, but most likely this is because the `\` has a special meaning in double quotes.
 Use a double-escape:

```
new RegExp("switchview\\(", "i");
```

Or you can also write:

```
var pattern:RegExp = /switchview\(/i;
... match(pattern)
```

Comment: Yes - apparently you need double escapes when using quotes.  So ( needs \\\(, \d is \\d, etc.  Lame.